# Should a void pointer need to be dereferenced everytime even after typecasting it?

Tags: c

Even after typecasting to integer type in malloc declaration, the ptr cannot be used without typecasting it explicitly every time whenever I dereference the pointer. Can anyone explain why the pointer is not converted to int* forever after I typecasted it.

```
void *ptr;
ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
*ptr = 1; // This line does not work even after typecasting in the above line
*(int*)ptr = 1; //This line works
```

Comment: The void pointer doesn't know what type it's pointing to, so you need to cast it every time you use it.

Comment: As soon as you assign a something-pointer to a `void *`, it becomes a `void *` again. That's how C++ works.

Comment: Does that mean the pointer is not converted to integer permanently after typecasting it?

Comment: Correct. If you assign a `float` to an `int`, your `int` variable is still an `int`. Nobody cares that a `float` value was assigned to it. Once an `int` always an `int`. Once a `void *` always a `void *`. There's nothing special about a `void *` that makes this type work any differently than any other type.

Comment: It's time to invest into a good C++ book. Seriously.

Comment: preferably a book that uses new and delete rather than malloc and void *

Comment: If you want `ptr` to be `int *` then just say `int *ptr;`

Comment: To simplify, what would you expect `ptr` to be if you wrote it like `void *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));`?

Comment: C++ doesn't have something analogous to Kotlin's [smart casting](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts).

Comment: Is it a C code or C++ code? It's not idiomatic in either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the declaration of `ptr` in your first line. You seem to want it to be

```
int *ptr; /* NOT void* */
```

Otherwise you will have to cast it every time. C/C++ use compile time declarations and the cast on the `malloc` has no effect after the line on which it appears. In particular

```
ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); /* the (int*) HAS NO EFFECT when ptr is declared void* */
```